# How to control the two threads order?

Tags: c#

I have a program that receives notifications from `SQL` and runs them in `threads`. Receive client and address inserts and This information is transferred to another database, so far all right, the problem is that from a `stored procedure` is made an insert Both in the client and in the direction that activates both notifications almost at the same time, and I need to pass First the information of the client and then the address, but sometimes it happens backward and I get an error on the other side, Is there any way to make first pass one information and then another?, the address has the customer ID so My main idea is to check with a method if the client is already in the database and repeat until it is true, but I Like other options.

Comment: **Pro Tip** paragraphs and line spacing make a question more readable and approachable. Also, when you are explaining code its best to insert code, its less ambiguous and can be easily read

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: An [mcve] would be awesome here.

Comment: Post code from where these threads are initialized and started. Maybe some thread synchronization technique can be applied there. But only after looking at some code.

Answer (score 0):

Put the requests in a queue and process them sequentially.